# Dynamically create multiple slide shows using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I want to create a slide show of the number of objects in the "SliderArray" array when I click on the button.

The current [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3gptumh/30/) is available in standalone mode.

When I take the function into the loop, things get messy

```
var myFunction = function() {
if (counter == 0) {
  $('#' + sliderarray[0].slaytarray[counter].id).fadeIn();
  frametime = sliderarray[0].slaytarray[counter].frame_time * 1000;
  counter++;
} else if (counter == sliderarray[0].slaytarray.length) {
  $('#' + sliderarray[0].slaytarray[counter - 1].id).fadeOut();
  counter = 0;
  frametime = 0;
} else {
  $('#' + sliderarray[0].slaytarray[counter - 1].id).fadeOut();
  $('#' + sliderarray[0].slaytarray[counter].id).fadeIn();
  frametime = sliderarray[0].slaytarray[counter].frame_time * 1000;
  counter++;
}

timeout = setTimeout(myFunction, frametime);

}

var timeout = setTimeout(myFunction, frametime);
```

And here my objects
[image]

Comment: It's a little unclear what exactly you wish to achieve. The JSFiddle seems to cycle through colors when I click on it. What do you mean by "things get messy?"

Comment: When you click on the button, only the top slideshow is working. Inside the "slider array" object there are 2 slide objects. What I want is the operation of these two slide shows when clicked on the button. I did not solve this problem with a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is "messy" because you never manipulate the second `slider`.

I fixed it by using a `.forEach` on the `sliderarray`:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    if (counter == 0) {
        sliderarray.forEach(function (slider) {
            $('#' + slider.slaytarray[counter].id).fadeIn();
            frametime = slider.slaytarray[counter].frame_time * 1000;
        });
        counter++;
    } else if (counter == sliderarray[0].slaytarray.length) {
        sliderarray.forEach(function (slider) {
            $('#' + slider.slaytarray[counter - 1].id).fadeOut();
        });
        counter = 0;
        frametime = 0;
    } else {
        sliderarray.forEach(function (slider) {
            $('#' + slider.slaytarray[counter - 1].id).fadeOut();
            $('#' + slider.slaytarray[counter].id).fadeIn();
            frametime = slider.slaytarray[counter].frame_time * 1000;
    });
    counter++;
}
```

There is still a problem for the frametime because you're only using once when two are needed. I'll just let you look into it.

See [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sp0hyzor/)

Comment: Perfect and simple solution without frametime problem i'm work for this..Thank you brother..